# Javafx - combo-box text-field bg color

Tags: java, javafx

I've googled and searched in SO but unfortunately, I didn't find the way how to make a **Non-Editable combobox** contain a *textfield with white background* via css.

In other words, how do I make a **Non-Editable combobox** appear like an Editable combobox (i.e. the same focus, arrow button, etc)?

The code:

```
.combo-box .text-field{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @Uluk Biy Ok. I could use and ChoiceBox, but then how to make ChoiseBox with wite background?

Comment: What about the answers below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add this css:

```
.combo-box > .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 -3 1 1, 1 -2 1 1 ;
}
```

But to get all the styles from edditable combobox you have to find `.combo-box-base:editable` from `/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css` and replace .text-field with .list-cell, because only editable combobox has .text-field

```
.combo-box > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.333333em 0.666667em; /* 4 8 4 8 */
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-content-display: LEFT;
}

.combo-box  > .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 3 3 0, 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0;
}
.combo-box > .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
    linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 1 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 2 0 0 2;
}
.combo-box:contains-focus {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3;
}
.combo-box:focused > .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color:
    -fx-control-inner-background,
    -fx-faint-focus-color,
    linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 1 1, 1 0 1 1, 3 2 3 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 2 0 0 2, 1 0 0 1, 0;
}

.combo-box :contains-focus > .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color, -fx-faint-focus-color, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1, 2, 1, 2.6;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0, 0 1 1 0, 0 1 1 0;
}
```

And here is the result:

1-st box styled with just 2 lines

2-nd has testComboBox2.setEditable(true);

3-d styled with big css from default styles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want because I can't imagine well "not editable combobox with a textfield" but maybe a comma between them?

```
.combo-box, .text-field{
-fx-background-color: white;
}
```

This is my output:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, it is not the same. Because your arrow is not like in editable. Besides you loose focus color.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this for a project. I hope you haven't been smashing your head against it as long as I did...

```
.combo-box:disabled, .combo-box:disabled > .text-field {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Then, if your ComboBox is disabled, it will look normal, but you can not engage the drop down or type into the editable text field.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the misunderstanding. Thought you were asking for disabled combo boxes.